# Django not identifying User custom model

Tags: django, django-models

Error: django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: AUTH_USER_MODEL refers to model 'users.User' that has not been installed

settings.py
INSTALLED_APPS = [
...
'apps.users',
...
]
AUTH_USER_MODEL='users.User'

Resolver o erro. Sem mudar o nome do app no INSTALLED_APPS

Comment: should be `INSTALLED_APPS = ['users']` normally.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: More than often we run into errors of this sort because we forgot to update migrations. I'm not assuming this is the problem. Just a reminder.